# Get photo number from id?

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of photos in an array.

```
<div>
  <img id="photo1">
  <img id="photo2">
  <img id="photo3">
  <img id="photo4">
</div>
```

I have a slideshow. My slideshow works by showing the photo number based in the div.. i.e.

```
var photos = $('div img');
$(photos[0]).show();
```

Is there a quick way to get img position in the div? So #photo1 would be 0, #photo4 would be 3. If not.. what is the most efficient way to get the img id and return (number - 1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the index of the `photo3` use `$("#photo3").index()`.

Answer (score 1):

you should use eq method where you have to pass index.

```
photos.eq(0).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

to  find image id you can try this

```
var imgID = $('img').attr('id');
```

Comment: The image id was not something I was after. Thanks anyway